# Harmcrest jsonPath wrongly failing with double

Tags: spring, spring-test

I have following REST endpoint that returns a simple data class with two doubles

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public LatLng test() {
    return new LatLng(-26.733229893125923, -26.733229893125923);
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
mockMvc.perform(
    get("/test")
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
    .andExpect((jsonPath("$.latitude", is(-26.733229893125923))))
    .andExpect((jsonPath("$.longitude", is(-26.733229893125923))));
```

The test always fails with

> java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.latitude" Expected: is
>   <-26.733229893125923>
>        but: was <-26.733229893125923>

The stacktrace correctly shows them being the same values but the test still failed for some reason.

If I reduce the double precision by one the test works. The test also fails if I use `Matchers.closeTo(-26.733229893125923, 0.01)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The stacktrace correctly shows them being the same values but the test still failed for some reason.

That actually shows that their string representations (i.e., the result of invoking `toString()` on the objects) are the same. It does not show that the objects are equal in terms of `.equals()` semantics.

Thus, the `expected` object is likely a `Double`; whereas, the `actual` object is likely a `Float`.

If that's the case, the following should likely make your test pass.

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.latitude", is(-26.733229893125923f)))
```

If you're using Spring 4.3.15 or newer, you should be able to use the following as well.

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.latitude").value(is(-26.733229893125923), Double.class))
```